# Elegant Themes Chameleon Theme View Full Site Button For Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, responsive-design

If you have done this topic before please add your solution.

Here is what i am trying to do:

I used this solution https://github.com/chrismorata/Responsive-View-Full-Site 
but it requires jQuery 1.7+, however chameleon theme includes different JQuery. So, I added following code at the end;

```
<div class="rwd-display-options">
<span id="view-full" class="rwd-display-option">View Full Site</span>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/rwd-display.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But this "JQuery.min.js" file causes crash with existing JQuery. 
Is there a way to use this "JQuery.min.js" make only work with "rwd-display.js" and dont cause crashes with other part of site.

Comment: maybe noconflict() can help, but sometimes you just can't do it, depending on how the other code works...

Comment: can you not just update the themes jQuery? But it might be a good opportunity to rewrite the new code in vanilla js, `getElementsByTagName()` for the meta tag, etc.